# Data transfer from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, etl

I am dump about ODI Tool, but i just heard that we can use ODI for data moving from SQL Server 2005 to PostgreSQL easily can any one tell me how to do that (Like steps need to be followed)

and i dont know which tag is good for this Question

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to ODI tool, you can use it for loading data from pretty much any source to pretty much any target. I should mention though that this is quite an advanced tool with a steep learning curve, so if you want to do something quickly and just for one project, SSIS would be a better bet.

You can even use it from your laptop and you do not have to learn SSIS too much. There is also Import/Export Wizard that you can use that will build SSIS package for your to get data from source to target and you can save it for a future use and be done with it in 15 minutes.

ODI will require some extended setup before you can do anything. Once you learn it though, it is very advanced and customized tool that many companies use to complex ETL projects.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to use ODI, or how to implement an ETL solution in general?

If you're looking for an ETL tool that can move data from SQL Server to PostreSQL then some obvious options are:

- [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) (already included in SQL Server)
- A script or program that you write yourself in your preferred language (Perl, C#, whatever)
- A third-party tool that has some particular advantage in your environment (familiarity, cost etc.)
- A mix of solutions, e.g. use SSIS to export data to flat files; use PowerShell to compress, move them to another server and uncompress them; and use pgloader to load them

But no one can say which is the best ETL solution for your environment except you; you should do some research into the options that fit your needs and then make a decision.

Comment: hi thank you for your time and i am looking for how to use ODI